# http c++ library?

Tags: c++, http, libraries

Hi I am wondreing if there is some kind of C++ library that deals with HTTP, HTTPs, chunking etc. Google did not find anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe [libCURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm also using libCURL in my projects. It has bindings with many programming languages. (**[libcurl Bindings](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/bindings.html)**)
But using it without them is also very easy. Simplest example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "curl.haxx.se");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This example and many more can be found [**here**](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html).

Comment: since this is a C++ question, a C++ example using the C++ bindings would be more appropriate http://curlpp.org/index.php/examples

Answer (score 2):

[cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/latest/index.html). It is pure C++ and it is linked to the boost community, although not yet part of boost.